# JasperReports SubDataset for jr:table from JasperPrint fillReport

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, jasper-reports, pojo

I'm trying to get a data source from java into a dataset on jrxml to display on a jr:table but it crashes when i try to get the data into the dataset, so i guess the error comes from the import or the parameter with the data type that handles the data source. The error is displayed below. Any ideas? Ty all.

Error:

```
[JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRBeanCollectionDataSource cannot be resolved to a type
                value = ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRBeanCollectionDataSource)parameter_dados.getValue()); //$JR_EXPR_ID=8$
                          <---------------------------------------------------->
2. net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRBeanCollectionDataSource cannot be resolved to a type
                value = ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRBeanCollectionDataSource)parameter_dados.getValue()); //$JR_EXPR_ID=8$
                          <---------------------------------------------------->
3. net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRBeanCollectionDataSource cannot be resolved to a type
                value = ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRBeanCollectionDataSource)parameter_dados.getValue()); //$JR_EXPR_ID=8$
                          <----------------------------------------------------> 3 errors .]
```

Java Method that handles the Jasper Report:

```
public File getRelatorioPdf(AuditoriaEntity auditoriaEntity) throws JRException, IOException {

        File pdf = null;
        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("objetivo", "TESTE OBJETIVO");
        parametros.put("dataInicio", "09/05/2017");
        parametros.put("dataFim", "09/05/2017");
        parametros.put("equipa", "Equipa TESTE");
        parametros.put("coordenador", "Coordenador TESTE");
        parametros.put("processo", "PROCESSO TESTE");
        parametros.put("ambito", "AMBITO TESTE");

        //TESTE DE LISTA
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource dados = null;
        List <testeLista> teste = new ArrayList<testeLista>();
        teste.add(new testeLista("teste1", "1", "2"));
        teste.add(new testeLista("teste2", "3", "4"));
        teste.add(new testeLista("teste3", "5", "6"));
        teste.add(new testeLista("teste4", "7", "8"));
        teste.add(new testeLista("teste5", "9", "10"));
        teste.add(new testeLista("teste6", "11", "12"));
        dados = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(teste);

        final String jasperReportPath = "jasper-reports/relatorio_auditoria/relatorio_auditoria.jrxml";
        InputStream inputStreamTemplate = this.environment.resourceAsStream(jasperReportPath);

        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStreamTemplate);
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parametros, dados);
        pdf = File.createTempFile("temp", ".pdf");
        pdf.deleteOnExit();
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, new FileOutputStream(pdf));

        return pdf;
    }
```

Java Class testeLista:

```
public class testeLista{
    private String naoConformidade;
    private String numNC;
    private String numOBS;

    public testeLista(String naoConformidade, String numNC, String numOBS) {
        this.naoConformidade = naoConformidade;
        this.numNC = numNC;
        this.numOBS = numOBS;
    }

    public String getNaoConformidade() {
        return naoConformidade;
    }

    public void setNaoConformidade(String naoConformidade) {
        this.naoConformidade = naoConformidade;
    }

    public String getNumNC() {
        return numNC;
    }

    public void setNumNC(String numNC) {
        this.numNC = numNC;
    }

    public String getNumOBS() {
        return numOBS;
    }

    public void setNumOBS(String numOBS) {
        this.numOBS = numOBS;
    }
}
```

Jasper Report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1e9d3196-bef6-4b86-97d2-b6eb6e579cec">
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"></import>
    <!--<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>-->
    <subDataset name="Dataset1">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="naoConformidade" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="numNC" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="numOBS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="dados" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="coordenador" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="processo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ambito" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="objetivo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="equipa" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="dataFim" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="dataInicio" class="java.lang.String"/>
<pageFooter>
        <band height="160" splitType="Stretch">
            <!--<textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{naoConformidade}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="0" width="30" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{numNC}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="0" width="30" height="20"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{numOBS}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>-->

            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="160" height="20">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1">
                        <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{dados}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <!--<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{dados}]]></dataSourceExpression>-->
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="100">
                        <jr:detailCell height="20">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{naoConformidade}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="30">
                        <jr:columnHeader height="20">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="20"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[NC]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell height="20">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="20"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{numNC}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="30">
                        <jr:columnHeader height="20">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="20"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[OBS]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell height="20">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="20"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{numOBS}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the variable "dados" does not have an acceptable "java object type" in its constructor at this line.

```
dados = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(teste);
```

The variable reference "teste" should be a java.util.Collection **OF JavaBean objects.**

note that the class "JRBeanCollectionDataSource" should hold only references (as a java.util.Collection) to **the "registered bean classes" of the server configuration of the application the code is running in.**

When adding Java Beans to the list, their id reference should be the same as in the configuration file although the server thread can have its "Application" object accessed to obtain a collection of all the beans configured.

However, Jasper also goes a lot further, inclusive a deliberate report server and engine.

You should specify if it is a deliberate lone Jasper report server or an integration to an earlier server type with a JSP engine and servlet engine system.

TOO

"testeLista" object is more sensibly written as TestLista

```
// Declare case sensitive class name first letter is capital (java convention of class naming)
public class TesteLista{.....
// normal class name first letter capitalized
List <TesteLista> teste = new ArrayList<TesteLista>();
```